# Framework suggestion to convert JSON to SQL

Tags: sql, json

Are there any frameworks that can converts JSON to SQL. We have MDX which is for OLAP based systems. The use-case that I am working on allows users to add flat data and create a table and run SQL on top of it. We are trying to build an abstraction layer that can convert a JSON to SQL at runtime.